# What is the sort order of document.cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

In what order the cookies are sorted in document.cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends completely on how the site that sets the cookies, sets them.

Comment: I have cookies from multiple sites. I think it may depend on JS implementaion and vary by browser.

Comment: Well, there you have your answer.